# Dialogflow - How to get bot to answer correctly with multiple probing questions leading to many different intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a question-answer bot that needs at least 2 questions before it gives them an answer. My problem is, the probing questions are exactly the same but require different responses based on the end users answers. I am trying to have the bot suggest products based on the type of animal they have.

For example,
User: "I need help with product recommendations"
Bot: "What products do you need?"
User: "I need shampoo"
Bot: "What type of animal do you have?"
User: "A dog"
Bot: "For a dog, I would recommend {this} shampoo"

However, as I have so many animals and so many products, it often gets confused and will answer the last question with either the wrong animal and the right product, or it will answer with the right animal but the wrong product.

I have been playing around with the contexts and entities, but I have too many animals to create a context for each, as I can only have a max of 5. The entities don't really seem to help, it functions the same regardless of if the animals and products are tagged or not.

I am new to all of this and don't know any coding, but I was hoping there's someone out there a bit more experienced at this than I am and can help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.